# How to program to solve Schrodinger Equation in 1D

Tags: physics, matlab

I am a university student and trying to write a program to solve 1-D Schrodinger's equation with some kinda of potential equations.

I am not a CS major so really have no clue to start.

I did research online but didn't find thing that is suitable for entry level :( The only thing I understand now is that I probably need to use some algorithm solving differential equations

Could anyone give me some suggestions or references on how I could start? For example, how to transform the physical problem into computer science program and what kinda algorithm I should look for?

I am interested in computational so trying on this HARD problem ;)

Thank you all!

Comment: It is almost always better to start with EASY problems. I'm a physicist too; believe me when I tell you that that doesn't make you a good programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. go to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)
2. search for :how can i solve Schrodinger in  matlab
3. go to [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/103594)
4. Return [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot. I will start on that!